# Dynamically set Selected Item for RibbonComboBox (on runtime)?

Tags: c#, combobox, vsto, ribbonx

How to set selected-item programatically for `RibbonComboBox` in VSTO?
I use `C#`.

i.e.

```
myRibbonCB.SelectedItem = "label-name";
```

doesnt exist.

Comment: Possibly duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575080/how-to-set-selected-item-on-custom-dropdown-ribbon-control

Comment: You need to define callbacks in the ribbon and implement those callbacks in your C# code. The duplicate link above shows a VBA solution, try the following for a C# VSTO example: http://blogs.infoextract.in/office-ribbon-customization-vsto-using-c/

Comment: @OlleSjögren You might post your comment as answer, i'll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define callbacks in the ribbon and implement those callbacks in your C# code. Try the following link for a C# VSTO example: 
http://blogs.infoextract.in/office-ribbon-customization-vsto-using-c/

In short:

**Ribbon XML**:

```
<toggleButton id="toggleButton1" onAction="OnActionCallback" />
```

**C#**:

```
public void OnActionCallback(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool isPressed)
{
    if (control.Id == "checkBox1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + control.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked a different control.");
    }
}
```