# Indirectly Populate Drop Down On Custom Ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

As a follow up to this question:

[VBA - Populate Custom Ribbon Drop Down/List Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146927/vba-populate-custom-ribbon-drop-down-list-box?noredirect=1#comment100810730_57146927)

I need to be able to populate my second drop down based on the selection from my first drop down. Similar to the "indirect" data validation.

I am struggling to "choose" the drop down in my vba.

***Code:***

**XML:**

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="LoadParameters">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="myCustomTab" label="Currencies">

                <group id="displayCurrencies" label="Selected Currencies">

                    <dropDown   
                        id="ddlBaseCurrency"
                        label="Base Currency"
                        getItemCount="getItemCountDDL"
                        getItemLabel="getItemLabelDDL"
                        getSelectedItemIndex="getItemIndexDDL"
                        onAction="onActionDDL"

                    />

                    <dropDown   
                        id="ddlCurrencyPair"
                        label="Currency Pair"
                        getItemCount="getItemCountDDL"
                        getItemLabel="getItemLabelDDL"
                        getSelectedItemIndex="getItemIndexDDL"
                        onAction="onActionDDL"
                    />

                    <dropDown   
                        id="ddlLongShort"
                        label="Long/Short"
                        getItemCount="getItemCountDDL"
                        getItemLabel="getItemLabelDDL"
                        getSelectedItemIndex="getItemIndexDDL"
                        onAction="onActionDDL"
                    />

                </group>

            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**VB**

```
Option Explicit

    'Global Variables:
    Public MyRibbonUI As IRibbonUI
    Public count As Integer
    Public strList As String
    Public stringVar As String
    Public baseCurrency As String
    Public ddl_Index As Integer
    Public ddl_Label As String
    Public baseCurrencies As Variant

    'Callback for customUI.onLoad
    Sub loadParameters(ribbon As IRibbonUI)

        Set MyRibbonUI = ribbon
        strList = ""
        count = 0
        stringVar = ""
        baseCurrency = "base"
        baseCurrencies = Array("USD", "EUR", "GBP", "AUD", "NZD", "CAD", "CHF", "METALS", "OIL")

    End Sub

    'Callback for ddlBaseCurrency getItemCount
    Sub getItemCountDDL(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef count)

        'On Error Resume Next
        Dim currencyPairs As Variant
        Dim index As Integer
        Dim i As Long

        Select Case control.id

            Case "ddlBaseCurrency"

                For i = 0 To UBound(baseCurrencies)

                    If baseCurrency <> "--SELECT--" And baseCurrency <> "base" And InStr(baseCurrency, "/") = 0 Then

                        strList = baseCurrency

                        count = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Rows.count

                        Exit For

                    ElseIf baseCurrency = "base" Or baseCurrency = "--SELECT--" Then

                        strList = "Currency"

                        count = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Columns.count

                        Exit For

                    End If

                Next

            Case "ddlLongShort"

                strList = "ExecutionType"

                count = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Rows.count

        End Select

    End Sub

    'Callback for ddlBaseCurrency getItemLabel
    Sub getItemLabelDDL(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef label)

        Dim rngML As Range
        Dim i As Long

        Select Case control.id

            Case "ddlBaseCurrency"

                For i = 0 To UBound(baseCurrencies)

                    If baseCurrency <> "--SELECT--" And baseCurrency <> "base" And InStr(baseCurrency, "/") = 0 Then

                        strList = baseCurrency

                        Exit For

                    ElseIf baseCurrency = "base" Or baseCurrency = "--SELECT--" Then

                        strList = "Currency"

                        Exit For

                    End If

                Next

            Case "ddlLongShort"

                strList = "ExecutionType"

        End Select

        Set rngML = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange
        label = rngML.Cells(index + 1)

        ddl_Label = label

    End Sub

    'Callback for ddlBaseCurrency getSelectedItemIndex
    Sub getItemIndexDDL(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef index)

        'Ensure first item in dropdown is displayed.
        Select Case control.id

            Case Is = "ddlBaseCurrency"

                index = 0

            Case Is = "ddlLongShort"

                index = 0

        End Select

        ddl_Index = index

    End Sub

    'Callback for ddlBaseCurrency onAction
    Sub onActionDDL(control As IRibbonControl, id As String, selectedIndex As Integer)

        Dim i As Long
        Dim arrayCount As Long

        arrayCount = 0

        Select Case control.id

            Case "ddlBaseCurrency"

                For i = 0 To UBound(baseCurrencies)

                    If baseCurrencies(i) = baseCurrency Then

                        arrayCount = 1

                    ElseIf baseCurrency = "base" Or baseCurrency = "--SELECT--" Then

                        arrayCount = 2

                    End If

                Next

                Select Case arrayCount

                    Case 1

                        Call getItemCountDDL(control, count)
                        Call getItemIndexDDL(control, ddl_Index)
                        Call getItemLabelDDL(control, ddl_Index, ddl_Label)
                        Call GetListOfCurrencies

    '                    strList = baseCurrency
    '                    baseCurrency = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Rows(CLng(selectedIndex + 1)).Value

                    Case 2

                        strList = "Currency"

                        baseCurrency = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Columns(CLng(selectedIndex + 1)).Value

                End Select

            Case "ddlLongShort"

                strList = "ExecutionType"

        End Select

    End Sub

    Public Sub GetListOfCurrencies()

        If MyRibbonUI Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        MyRibbonUI.InvalidateControl ("ddlBaseCurrency")
        DoEvents

    End Sub
```

I was thinking I could do something like:

```
For each control on tab("custom tab")    
    bCurrency = Findcontrol.control.id("ddlBaseCurrency").Value
    cPair = Findcontrol.control.id("ddlCurrencyPair")

    For i = 0 To UBound(currencyPairs)    
        If bCurrency = currencyPairs(i) Then        
            'Do the indirect validation in here    
        End If    
    Next    
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried the sample in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43583223/1490783 If you can get the sample to work, you could then combine it with your logic above and get your desired result. Also, you probably need to provide your Custiom UI XML to get more specific help.

Comment: @OlleSjögren Thank you for the reply and having a look! :) I did look at your post but I cannot get the second DDL to populate without calling an actual "callback" method. At the moment, the above VBA works to an extent but the logic is not right somewhere because it is invalidating both drop downs - even after selecting a value in the second drop down.

Comment: @OlleSjögren YOU ARE A GENIUS!! I managed to solve it thanks to your example :D Answer posted below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After DAYS of searching the internet and the help of **Eugene** and **Olle** above, I eventually cracked the code!

So, the first thing was that I had to update my XML to have **UNIQUE** callbacks for **EACH DDL**. My code therefore looks like this now:

***Code:***

**XML:**

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="LoadParameters">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
         <tabs>
                <tab id="myCustomTab" label="Currencies">

                    <group id="displayCurrencies" label="Selected Currencies">

                    <dropDown   
                        id="ddlBaseCurrency"
                        label="Base Currency"
                        getItemCount="getItemCountDDL1"
                        getItemLabel="getItemLabelDDL1"
                        getSelectedItemIndex="getItemIndexDDL1"
                        onAction="onActionDDL"
                    />

                    <dropDown   
                        id="ddlCurrencyPair"
                        label="Currency Pair"
                        getItemCount="getItemCountDDL2"
                        getItemLabel="getItemLabelDDL2"
                        getSelectedItemIndex="getItemIndexDDL2"
                        onAction="onActionDDL"
                    />

                    <dropDown   
                        id="ddlLongShort"
                        label="Long/Short"
                        getItemCount="getItemCountDDL3"
                        getItemLabel="getItemLabelDDL3"
                        getSelectedItemIndex="getItemIndexDDL3"
                        onAction="onActionDDL"
                    />

                </group>

            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Notice that the `getItemCount, getItemLabel, getSelectedItemIndex` are equal to **unique** callbacks, named `getItemCountDDL, getItemLabelDDL, getItemIndexDDL` respectively, with their unique identifiers being the numbers of each DDL (**DDL 1 through 3**).

**VBA:**

```
    Option Explicit

    'Global Variables:
    Public MyRibbonUI As IRibbonUI
    Public strList As String
    Public baseCurrency As String
    Public ddl_Index As Integer
    Public ddl_Label As String
    Public baseCurrencies As Variant
    Public stringVar As String

    'Callback for customUI.onLoad
    Sub loadParameters(ribbon As IRibbonUI)

        Set MyRibbonUI = ribbon
        strList = ""
        baseCurrency = "base"
        ddl_Index = 0
        stringVar = ""

    End Sub

    '------- Drop Down List 1
    Sub getItemCountDDL1(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef count)

        strList = "Currency"

        count = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Columns.count

    End Sub

    Sub getItemLabelDDL1(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef label)

        Dim rngML As Range

        strList = "Currency"

        Set rngML = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange
        label = rngML.Cells(index + 1)

        ddl_Label = label

    End Sub

    Sub getItemIndexDDL1(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef index)

        If ddl_Index <> 0 Then

            index = ddl_Index

        Else

            index = 0

        End If

        ddl_Index = index

    End Sub

    '------- Drop Down List 2
    Sub getItemCountDDL2(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef count)

        strList = baseCurrency

        If baseCurrency <> "--SELECT--" And baseCurrency <> "base" Then

            count = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Rows.count

        End If

    End Sub

    Sub getItemLabelDDL2(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef label)

        Dim rngML As Range

        strList = baseCurrency

        If baseCurrency <> "--SELECT--" And baseCurrency <> "base" Then

            Set rngML = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange
            label = rngML.Cells(index + 1)

        End If

    End Sub

    Sub getItemIndexDDL2(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef index)

        index = 0

    End Sub

    '------- Drop Down List 3
    Sub getItemCountDDL3(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef count)

        strList = "ExecutionType"

        count = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Rows.count

    End Sub

    Sub getItemLabelDDL3(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef label)

        Dim rngML As Range

        strList = "ExecutionType"

        Set rngML = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange
        label = rngML.Cells(index + 1)

    End Sub

    Sub getItemIndexDDL3(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef index)

        index = 0

    End Sub

    'Callback for onAction
    Sub onActionDDL(control As IRibbonControl, id As String, selectedIndex As Integer)

        Dim i As Long
        Dim arrayCount As Long

        arrayCount = 0

        Select Case control.id

            Case "ddlBaseCurrency"

                strList = "Currency"
                ddl_Index = selectedIndex
                baseCurrency = ThisWorkbook.Names(strList).RefersToRange.Columns(CLng(selectedIndex + 1)).Value
                Call invalidateRibbon

            Case "currencyPair"

            Case "ddlLongShort"

        End Select

    End Sub

'-----Invalidate Ribbon
    Public Sub invalidateRibbon()

        If MyRibbonUI Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        MyRibbonUI.Invalidate
        DoEvents

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't call ribbon callbacks in the code. Instead, you need to use the `Invalidate` or `InvalidateControl` methods of the `IRibbonUI` when you want your custom UI to be refreshed/invalidated.

The object that is returned by the onLoad procedure specified on the customUI tag. The object contains methods for invalidating control properties and for refreshing the user interface.

The `IRibbonUI` object does not generate events in its interaction with the user. Instead, ribbon elements perform callbacks to your code, and the linkage between ribbon elements and your code is defined in the XML that describes your ribbon additions.

For information about the callback functions available for each UI element, search for "How can I determine the correct signatures for each callback procedure?" in [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)).

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 

Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
 Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 

Sub myFunction() 
 MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
End Sub
```

And in the custom XML markup you just need to define the `onLoad` callback:

```
<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddInInitialize" …>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. :) I have changed the code to not have callbacks but still I don't seem to be able to populate the second drop down based on the value from the first drop down. I need to do validation between the two drop downs.

Comment: You need to use callbacks. I'd suggest posting the code you have now.

Comment: Thank you again for the reply. I worked on the code a bit on the weekend and you'll notice I ended up putting the calls to the 3 callbacks in the `onAction` callback. I don't seem to be able to populate the second drop down based on the selection of something in the primary drop down. So what I am doing is grabbing the value of the first one and storing it, then invalidating the control and re-populating it with the list I require. If you have some better way of doing this, please share. It's driving me insane :/ - Or alternatively if you can assist in populating the second DDL... :)

Comment: Thank you once again. I didn't quite understand the way it works but then I read on @olle post that when invalidating the ribbon, the selectedItemIndex is automatically called again. And then I knew why you were saying not have callbacks in the code the way I was using it. So thank you! :)